# Adding descriptive text to column names

Tags: r, dataframe, tibble

I recently loaded in some data from a world bank API and when I viewed the dataframe with tibble's `view()` function, I noticed some nice descriptive metadata text just below the column name, like in the image below

[image: screenshot of the panel]

I would like to be able to reproduce this effect in the future,  `attributes(mtcars)$subheaders <- c("where","are","my","subheaders")` did not work for me and I appear to lack the proper technical vocabulary to be able to search for the solution.

Comment: What class is the object?  It's probably not a standard dataframe.  Use `class(obj)` to see.

Comment: The following was the result of class(obj) -> [1] "data.table" "data.frame"

Comment: Okay, the `"data.table"` indicates that this is an object from the `data.table` package.  I don't know that package well enough to advise you, but you can read its documentation, as well as packages `expss` and `haven`, which do this kind of thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put all kinds of information in the attributes. Some packages add labels and extra information to factor vectors for instance.

```
df <- data.frame(a = 10)
attr(df$a, "subheader") <- "description of a"
 
>attr(df$a, "subheader")
[1] "description of a"
> 
> str(df)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ a: num 10
  ..- attr(*, "subheader")= chr "description of a"
```

and you can add a function to get the subheader

```
subheader <- function(vec) {
  attr(vec, "subheader")
}
  
subheader(df$a)
```

**EDIT**

To have the description show up in `View()` you can add `label` as the name of the attribute.

```
df <- data.frame(a = 10)
attr(df$a, "label") <- "description of a"
```

Comment: Hi, I tried the method you described above and it does indeed add an attribute you can see when you call upon  `str()`, however, the description does not show up on the view pane as shown in the image in the question which is what I am looking for. unless I am missing a step? when you call upon `view()` do you see the description on the pane?

Comment: View recognizes `label`, change `subheader` for `label` and you'll see it show up in `View()`